# How to make a category comparison matrix in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing 3 columns. One ID, and two category columns. The two types of categories are not the same. What I would like as a result is a matrix with rows as one category, columns as the other category, and the values would be number of these cases.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable
(id serial PRIMARY KEY,
category_1 integer,
category_2 integer);

INSERT INTO myschema.mytable(category_1, category_2)
VALUES
(1,10),
(1,20),
(1,20),
(1,20),
(2,60),
(2,40),
(3,10),
(3,40);
```

So my table looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to have as a result is this:

[image]

This result was produced using this query:

```
SELECT distinct(a.category_1),b.count AS c_10,c.count AS c_20,d.count AS c_40,e.count AS c_60 FROM myschema.mytable AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_1, count(id) FROM myschema.mytable WHERE category_2 = 10 GROUP BY category_1) AS b
ON a.category_1 = b.category_1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_1, count(id) FROM myschema.mytable WHERE category_2 = 20 GROUP BY category_1) AS c
ON a.category_1 = c.category_1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_1, count(id) FROM myschema.mytable WHERE category_2 = 40 GROUP BY category_1) AS d
ON a.category_1 = d.category_1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_1, count(id) FROM myschema.mytable WHERE category_2 = 60 GROUP BY category_1) AS e
ON a.category_1 = e.category_1
ORDER BY category_1
```

My main concerns with this is that it's way too long and I have to know the unique values in advance, of at least one of the categories. I assume I could write a function for this, but I think I overcomplicated this problem, and there must be an easier way to do this.

I just found out about the `tablefunc` module and the `crosstab` functions, but I am not sure yet how to use them.

Comment: Are other values on category_2 besides 10,20,40,60 ? If not a simple conditional aggregation will do the trick for you https://dbfiddle.uk/apmkKxlX

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This makes a little simpler, but unfortunately yes, there are other values. What I was looking for is a general solution to an artbitrary number of categories.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) you have a  detailed explained answer

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!